# Two foreign keys to same primary table

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two classes: Customer and Association.

A customer can have an association with many customers. Each association is of a defined type (Family, Friend, etc) i.e Customer A is a friend of Customer B. Customer A is related to Customer C. The type of association is defined by an enum AssociationType.

In order to create this in EF i've defined the following classes

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
}

public class Association
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int AssociatedCustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer AssociatedCustomer { get; set; }   

    public AssociationType AssociationType { get; set; }
}
```

I've removed the Data Annotations as I was unable to get this to compile. I get the error:

> "Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not
>   contain model metadata".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens sometimes when an error occurs during database creation. The database schema is created then - except the `__MigrationHistory` table. When you run your application again EF wants to check against the `__MigrationHistory` table if the schema is still up-to-date with the model and if that table doesn't exist it throws the exception you are having.

To fix the problem either delete the database manually or set the initializer to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>` (with `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>())` - only *once*. After the DB is created set it back to your original initializer.

BTW: For your model you will have to specify explicitly that `Customer.Associations` is related to `Association.Customer`, either with data annotations...

```cs
[InverseProperty("Customer")]
public virtual ICollection<Association> Associations { get; set; }
```

...or with Fluent API:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Associations)
    .WithRequired(a => a.Customer)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.CustomerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Slauma, 
your answer got us going in the right direction.
We added the following configuration to the Association configuration:

```
HasRequired(x => x.AssociatedCustomer).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```